# When calling to NSOpenPanel's runModal, my application will not properly terminate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I'm writing a simple Cocoa Application, no core data or multiple document support.  Running on a Mac Pro, OS X 10.6.6, Xcode 3.2.3.

I have reduced my application to the following code in my AppDelegate class:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openPanel runModal];

    return;
}
```

From within the debugger, I will run my application.  As expected a somewhat not-to-useful OpenPanel will appear.  I will click Cancel and it will disappear.  All this is as expected.  When I click [Command + Q] to Quit the application, the UI will go away but the debugger will indicate that the application is still running (as does the console output).

Based upon all the information I'm reading, I should not have to do anything else in order for this to run right.  I've downloaded several examples on the Open Panel's usage but most use the **deprecated** methods of opening modal giving additional information as parameters.  FWIW, I tried those methods and am still seeing the same result.

One last item, when the Open dialog appears, just for an instant I see a message box asking me something to the extent if I want my application to receive incoming connections.  The dialog quickly disappears.  I don't know if that is part of my problem or not. [Update - this deals with my Firewall being turned on.]

Yes, I'm fairly new at Objective C but not at programming in general.  Any words of wisdom is greatly appreciated!

2011.02.07  - Update:

I have walked the debugger line by line without incident.  There is no indication of any program failure in the console window.

I say that the debugger is still active after [Command + Q] because the Stop Process toolbar button is still enabled as is the Break button.  Further the console indicates that after I tell the application to terminate (either via the menu or key command) that it is still running.  The following is the Complete console output from start of run to after I Quit the application.

```
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 62370]
Running...
```

The Activity Monitor (system tool) will show my application terminating (no longer shows up as a process) but the Debugger will still not transition to "edit" mode - if I tell Xcode to run the debugger again, it will ask me if it's OK to Stop the current debugging session.  If I was in Windows I would start looking for background threads keeping the process alive but as far as I know, NSOpenPanel should not be doing something like that.

I have further simplified the program to nothing more than creating a brand new Cocoa application and inserting the code snippet above - no other additions to the template project or updates in any way.

And lastly, when the application is run under the Leaks Performance Tool, everything runs fine when the panel is created but never used.  When created and actually used though, at the end of the run I will get the following message in the tool "insufficient task_for_pid privileges (leakagent64)".  Googling this hurts.  If I read it right, the debugger does not have sufficient permissions to fully kill the target process ???  Now that sounds stupid but ... It does not make sense!

Another update - I just downloaded and ran FunHouse, one of the SDK sample applications that also uses NSOpenPanel.  Well don't I feel special.  It exhibits the same exact behavior.  So from this I conclude either Apple has a bug in their code, my machine is special and messed up, and finally, it is Not my code that is at fault.  That being the best part.  Tomorrow, I will use a friends Mac and see if the same behavior is exhibited on his box.

This is just too weird.

Comment: When you sprinkle in a dummy `NSLog`-call or a breakpoint in that method: Do you see any output on the console/is your breakpoint hit? I'm thinking the dialog you mentioned, is the one that asks for your confirmation to attach the debugger to your application...

Comment: @danyowdee please refer to the updates in the text above.  The dialog mentioned (not OpenPanel) refers to allow remote / firewall access I believe.  I will be Googling that in a second here.

Comment: Well that's one belief too much :-p What _exactly_ is the dialog that pops up asking for (hit the disclosure-triangle in the dialog to view the details) and how did you react to it?

Answer (score 1):

I rebooted my box, took it to work and found it worked like a charm!  I will assume this is fixed and has nothing to do with any other connected devices at home as compared to at work.

If it re-exhibits at home, then it is a network/device issue.  Thanks all for your inputs and suggestions!  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

What, specifically, does the debugger say? It's possible that your program crashed, so the debugger is showing you information about the crash.

What if you omit any attempt to run an Open panel?

Comment: please refer to my updates above.  If I take the Open Panel code out, everything works fine.  If I create but do not runModel the panel, everything works fine.  It is only when I runModal the panel.